# Proving $X(p, q)$ is a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be a distinct prime with $q\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.  Let $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$ be the group of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ under multiplication.  Prove that the set $X(p,q)$ of all $x\in \mathbb{Z}_q^*$ satisfying $x^p=1$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$.

I tried to use subgroup criterion to prove $X(p,q)$ is a subgroup but didn't succeed. What kind of group theoretic properties should I used to prove $X(p,q)$ is a subgroup?

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  Closure?  What?

Comment: Also, this is really straightforward because $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$ is abelian.  All the prime business is a red herring.

Comment: The only interesting thing about $X(p,q)$ is that it is a *nontrivial* subgroup. This follows from $ \mathbb{Z}_q^*$ being cyclic.

Comment: @Randall I want to know existence of inverse for every element.

Comment: @aloevera  $(x^{-1})^p = (x^p)^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $A$ is an abelian group, then the set $A_n=\{ a \in A : a^n=1 \}$ is a subgroup of $A$. Indeed, $A_n$ is the kernel of $x \mapsto x^n$, which is a homomorphism because $A$ is abelian.

Whether $A_n$ is a *nontrivial* subgroup is a different question, which does have interesting answers.